Create the tag synonyms "cloaks" and "capes" for tag "accessories"
Just added the tag for "capes".  I feel "cloaks" can be a synonym, but honestly BOTH should be synonyms for "accessories"  Can someone with the appropriate amount of reputation please create the synonyms?

To be honest, I'm not quite sure we even need that tag

I'm an optimist.

Indeed, we've tended to use [tag:accessories] for those previously

Cool.  That works, but it is 100% not obvious.  You might want to consider adding some synonyms. Changing question to reflect that.
